Python-Redmine: get project by name
I want to use the python-redmine library
I would like to get access to a redmine-project by its name.
A redmine project has the attributes id, identifier and name, among others. I can access the project with the method redmine.project.get(...) and the values of id or the identifier. But is there also a way to get access via the value of the name? Or is there an other way to get the relation between name and id except the search in the result of redmine.project.all() In the examples in the documentation, the values for identifier and name are identical, but unfortunately this is not the case in my example.

You already found this (https://python-redmine.com/resources/project.html#get) which mentions no option to get access via the name. I also can't find another way to achieve this (besides what you suggested yourself).
